# Defining a minor of an array

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions, in the first one I generate a bidimensional array and in the second one I define an array minus the last line and column. However it does not work. The code is as follows:

```
function calcDet () {   
    var A = [];     //generates the array
    for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        A[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < k; j++) {   
            var id = "A" + (i + 1) + (j + 1);                   
            A[i][j] =  parseFloat(document.getElementById(id).value);               
        }
     }   
     return (A); 
}
function returnDet() {            
    var s;
    var A = calcDet();
    var smaller=[];                
    for (var i=0;i<k-1;i++) {
        smaller[i]=A[i]             
        for (var j=0;j<k-1;j++) {
            smaller[i][j]=A[i][j];
        }
    }
    alert (smaller);
}
```

Comment: why did you surround your return with bracket ? what your returnDet function output

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: the brackets are bec of speed and not paying attention. the default value of A is a 2 dimensional vector with all values 0. The returnDet() alerts only 0,0, that is only one line of A. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: the purpose of the code is to read values inserted dinamycally by the user and return an array that is one line smaller.

Comment: The reason you're getting 0,0 alerted is because of the line `smaller[i]=A[i]`. Say k = 2 then A is a 2*2 array. This line will then cause the first element of s to be a array of length 2. The inner loop of your returnDet function will just change values in this array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has undefined variables:
"k" seems to appear out of nowhere in both functions

Line 
var id = "A" + (i + 1) + (j + 1); 
will generate identical id for (some) different variations of i and j ([i = 11 and j = 1] == [i = 1 and j = 11]) that may be a cause of further errors

And it is always useful if you mention the error that you are getting - I would expect that your scripts would not run at all as they are...

Comment: +2 for that
k is a global variable defined at the start of <script>it's value is afterwards inserted by user and read by another function.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `k`, the length of the arrays, is defined nowhere. It should trow an error stating that.

You've got an error in your `returnDet` function. You first create the array `smaller`, then fill it with the "second-level" arrays from `A`:

```
    smaller[i]=A[i];
```

After that, you set each (except the last) of the values in `smaller[i]` to the value they already have:

```
    for (var j=0;j<k-1;j++) {
        smaller[i][j]=A[i][j];
    }
```

Yet, `smaller[i][k-1]` (the last one, which you don't want) still exists in the array, because both `smaller[i]` and `A[i]` point to the same object. What you want to do is:

```
function returnDet() {   
    var A = calcDet();
    var smaller = [];                
    for (var i=0; i<A.length-1; i++)
        smaller[i] = A[i].slice(0, -1);
    return smaller;
}
alert(returnDet());
```

[`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) copies the values from the array.

Comment: is it possible to declare it like this:  
var smaller = new array[A.lenght-1][A.length-1];          
   
      smaller[i][j]=A[i][j];
     }
    
        for (var i=0; i<A.length-1; i++)
     smaller[i] = A[i].slice(0, -1);

Comment: No. First, you can't declare multidimensional arrays like in Java, and second your for-loop seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Using built-in language features makes the code simpler to write and understand and also more efficient.

```
function trim (arr, r, c) {
  // Return a new array omitting the last r rows and c columns
  //    of a two dimensional array arr
  //    if not specified r and c default to 1

  arr = arr.slice (0, -(r || 1)); // remove last r rows
  arr.forEach (function (v, i, a) { a[i] = v.slice (0, -(c || 1)); });
  return arr;
}

[JSON.stringify (trim ([[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33]])),
 JSON.stringify (trim ([[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33]], 1, 2)),
 JSON.stringify (trim ([[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33]], 2, 1))]

/* Displays on JS console :
  ["[[11,12],[21,22]]", "[[11],[21]]", "[[11,12]]"]
*/
```